# SFTP job getting hung when running through shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, sftp, ftp

I have the below script to pull the file from another server.

```
#!/bin/bash

PROC_DATE=`date "+%Y%m%d"`
CURRENT_DATE=`date`
LOG_FILE="/home/tdata/dw/da/common/AWS_{PROC_DATE}.log"
AWS_CRED_FILE_NAME="/home/tdata/.aws/crnals"

cp -p ${AWS_CRED_FILE_NAME} ${AWS_CRED_FILE_NAME}_${PROC_DATE}
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
        echo "Credentials backup Failed\n" > ${LOG_FILE}
        cat ${LOG_FILE}
        exit 1;
else
        cd /home/tdata/.aws/
        sshpass -f .OP004 sftp -o ConnectionAttempts=1 tdata@OP004 << !
          cd /home/tdata/.aws/
            get crnals
        bye
!
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]
        then
                echo "The credentials copy from OP004 to CP104 failed. Please check and re-run manually" > ${LOG_FILE}
                cat ${LOG_FILE}
                exit 1;
        else
                echo "The credentials copy job completed successfully on ${CURRENT_DATE}" > ${LOG_FILE}
                exit 0;
        fi
fi
```

But it is getting struck for a very long time just like below and not getting completed at all.

```
$ sh -x AWS_CRED_COPY.sh
++ date +%Y%m%d
+ PROC_DATE=20221004
++ date
+ CURRENT_DATE='Tue Oct  4 02:07:56 CDT 2022'
+ LOG_FILE=/home/tdata/dw/da/common/AWS_20221004.log
+ AWS_CRED_FILE_NAME=/home/tdata/.aws/crnals
+ cp -p /home/tdata/.aws/crnals /home/tdata/.aws/crnals_20221004
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ cd /home/teradata/.aws/
+ sshpass -f .OP004 sftp -o ConnectionAttempts=1 teradata@OP004
```

I even tried adding Timeoutparameter for 20 Secs, that is also not working.

But when I run the SFTP block manually on CLI, it is working well and as expected.

```
tdata@cp114 -bash /opt/tdata/dw/data/common
$ sshpass -f .OP004 sftp -o ConnectionAttempts=1 teradata@OP004 << !
>           cd /home/teradata/.aws/
>             get crnals
>         bye
> !
Connected to ODRP5004.
sftp>           cd /home/teradata/.aws/
sftp>             get crnals
Fetching /home/tdata/.aws/crnals to canals
sftp>         bye
```

Any idea on how do we resolve this?

Comment: The question is tagged `bash`, the shebang is `#!/bin/bash`, it's not clear what your interactive shell is, but `sh -x AWS_CRED_COPY.sh` uses `sh`. I'm not saying this is the culprit; I'm saying it's good not to randomly switch shells when testing.

Comment: Understood. As you said that does't seem to be a culprit. But a good practice. Noted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully run a snippet like yours.

For running the command directly:

- Removing the password file, lead to an indefinite halt in the terminal.
- Giving a wrong password to the file, timed out with `Permission denied, please try again.`.

For running the script gave the same results as above.

**I guess you are missing the password file.**

Trivia: sshpass takes the string until first newline character.

Comment: The same script(without any changes), i tested and it runs successfully for any other file to be fetched from server A to B.
But getting hung indefinitely only for this particular file. The permissions on the file even looks good.

Comment: I disapprove the down vote on my answer the reason being I have arrived to the same symptom by some means, which I assumed to be the same cause as the one in this question. I would like to be acknowledged of other possible means if any.

Comment: @sabarishjackson within script the sshpass is invoked at location `/home/tdata/.aws/`, whereas it is run under `/opt/tdata/dw/data/common` manually. However, the password file is not referenced by absolute path. I even tried fetching the file into its same directory, this only empties the text file in my case, non-the-less it can still fetch it. I still suspect you are missing the password credential file.

Comment: I got it. This is a silly mistake. Thank you so much for pointing it out @cbugk

It is all good and running now.